# Sorting rows on Pandas dataframe based on multiple keywords

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I'm learning data science and am making a big data company list with some attributes.

Currently my dataframe, data, looks like this.

```
    company_url company tag_line    product data
0   https://angel.co/billguard  BillGuard   The fastest smartest way to track your spendin...   BillGuard is a personal finance security app t...   New York City · Financial Services · Security ...
1   https://angel.co/tradesparq Tradesparq  The world's largest social network for global ...   Tradesparq is Alibaba.com meets LinkedIn. Trad...   Shanghai · B2B · Marketplaces · Big Data · Soc...
2   https://angel.co/sidewalk   Sidewalk    Hoovers (D&B) for the social era    Sidewalk helps companies close more sales to s...   New York City · Lead Generation · Big Data · S...
3   https://angel.co/pangia Pangia  The Internet of Things Platform: Big data mana...   We collect and manage data from sensors embedd...   San Francisco · SaaS · Clean Technology · Big ...
4   https://angel.co/thinknum   Thinknum    Financial Data Analysis Thinknum is a powerful web platform to value c...   New York City · Enterprise Software · Financia...
```

I want to sort the "data" column with certain keywords such as "big data" and make a new dataframe with the rows.

I was thinking to first find the fitting rows and then, put them into a list and sort the dataframe, data, based on the rows list but I got an error for the first part.

My code:

```
comp_rows = []
a = ['Data','Analytics','Machine Learning','Deep','Mining']

for count, item in enumerate(data.data):
    if any(x in item for x in a):
        comp_rows.append(count)
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-174-afeee7d3d179> in <module>()
      3 
      4 for count, item in enumerate(data.data):
----> 5     if any(x in item for x in a):
      6         comp_rows.append(count)

<ipython-input-174-afeee7d3d179> in <genexpr>((x,))
      3 
      4 for count, item in enumerate(data.data):
----> 5     if any(x in item for x in a):
      6         comp_rows.append(count)

TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable
```

Could someone help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would work if your `data.data` was a list of strings, but a float was found there. Try to replace
`if any(x in item for x in a):` 
with  `if any(x in str(item) for x in a):`