# sort data based on keywords:python

Tags: python, dataframe, sorting, calculated-columns, group

1.How to sort columns in pyhton for particular keywords.

2.Once these are sorted how to create a new data frame for each keyword.

Attach here is the data being used [image: keywords have different color combination]

I used group by , sort but unable to execute it without errors.

Comment: Post your expected outputs & groupy code you used..It will be helpful

Comment: This may help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30075278/sorting-rows-on-pandas-dataframe-based-on-multiple-keywords